# How to pass prop values defined in Child comp to its Parent comp-reactJs

Tags: reactjs

I'm aware that the question have been addressed in the stack overflow, but for me I've more specific requirements. I want to define the value of a prop in the child comp and be able to pass its value to its grandparent comp.
Child component that I want to define the value:

```
const Child = React.createClass(

   onselect(status) {
    let testProp = {refs: this.refs.statetext, status:status}
  }
    render() {
         return (
                <Mycomp ref="statetext"/>
        );
});
```

Parent Comp:

```
const Parent = React.createClass(
//can I access the refs.statetext here???
        render() {
             return (
                    <Child/>
            );
    });
```

GrandParent Comp:

```
const GrandParent = React.createClass(
    //here I'd like to access the testProp defined in the Child comp
           closeMenu() {
              //should have the testProp value here to do some action in this function.
           }
            render() {
                 return (
                        <Parent onScroll={this.closeMenu.bind(this)}/>
                );
        });
```

Is this possible??

Comment: It doesnt answer your question but ref is usually a bad react practice, you just don't think in react. Why not initiate it in your grand parent or use a storeManager ?

Comment: @Nevosis using `ref` is fine in some circumstances and does not have anything to do with "thinking in React".  If you want an uncontrolled input, you have to use a `ref`, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you just need an event that will flow up to the `Grandfather` component.  In React, `props` flow down and `events` flow up.  So, the code below, bubbles the `onSelect` event up to the `Grandfather`, through `Parent`:

```
const Child = React.createClass(

   onselect(status) {
    let testProp = {refs: this.refs.statetext, status:status}
    this.props.onSelect(testProp);
  }
    render() {
         return (
                <Mycomp ref="statetext"/>
        );
});
```

Then:

```
const Parent = React.createClass(
//here I'd like to access the testProp defined in the Child comp
        render() {
             return (
                    <Child onSelect={this.props.onSelect} />
            );
    });
```

Then:

```
const GrandParent = React.createClass(
    //here I'd like to access the testProp defined in the Child comp
           closeMenu() {
              //should have the testProp value here to do some action in this function.
           }


           onSelect(testProp) {
              // here it is :)
              // you can now save it in state, so it will be available when the menu is closed.
              console.log(testProp);
           }

            render() {
                 return (
                        <Parent onScroll={this.closeMenu.bind(this)} onSelect={this.onSelect.bind(this)} />
                );
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare/initialize the variable in the `Grandfather` component and pass it down to the `Child` via props.
That's the point of presentational/container components.  If your `Child` component relies on the `Grandfather` component, that's where your state should be living.

Comment: I think the question is how to flow data in the opposite direction.  BTW, I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: But that's the correct answer to the question.  React is unidirectional, you can't pass props upwards through components.  You can use refs as a way to go around that, but it's not the *react* way to do it.

Comment: ok, so in this case, can I access the ref defined in my Child Comp inside the Grandparent?

Comment: Check out @DavinTryon's answer as I believe it has a better fit for what you're looking for.